# Usage before assignment detection in a Javascript code

Tags: javascript, static-analysis

I'm taking on a task to find issues in a large number of short Javascript codes. One of the things I'm looking for is instance of a variable usage before explicit assignment, like so:

```js
var a;
var b = a + 10; // a is not explicitly assigned a value
```

I've tried a few JS analysis tools like JSLint but they don't catch it. I'm hoping for a ready to use tool, as I'm pressed for time, but if there's a library that can be used for this with a bit of coding, then that's also helpful.

Comment: That’s not necessarily an issue when it comes to JavaScript, though…

Comment: True, but it does cause problems in the way my scripts are run as the data leaks from previous run of a script to the next invocation.

Comment: That seems odd. How *are* your scripts run?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to have such leaks unless you're using global variables (i.e. no `var` at all). Specifically, in JavaScript, this does not leak: `var b = a; var a;` (as long as it is in a function).

Comment: So how to you determine the value that *a* should be initialised to?

Comment: The scripts are run in Pentaho Data Integration suite. It seems that the script is run per row of data without reinitialization of the environment. So `var a;` initializes `a` to `undefined` the first time. But any subsequent times, it does nothing (try it).

Comment: Not sure about ready made solutions, but it shouldn't be too hard to create your own using http://esprima.org/.

Comment: @Amadan it's evidently not encapsulated in a function.